# Using reflection to dynamically call a function gives error: Non-static method requires a target

Tags: c#, asp.net, reflection

I am trying to use reflection to call a function dynamically and not quite sure how to make it work.

Here's my main function:

```
public partial class WorkerRole : RoleEntryPoint
{
    public override void Run()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            List<string> Firms = new List<string>();

            Firms.Add("BHP");

            foreach (string Firm in Firms)
            {

                typeof(WorkerRole).GetMethod(string.Format("{0}GetProfiles", Firm), BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public).Invoke(null, null);
            }

            break;
        }

        Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite);

    }
}
```

And here is an example of one of the functions I am dynamically calling (they all have the same signatures):

```
public partial class WorkerRole : RoleEntryPoint
{

    public List<string> BHPGetProfiles()
    {
        // Do tasks specific to BHP
    }
}
```

The error that I'm getting in the line that starts with typeof above is:

Additional information: Non-static method requires a target.

I don't want to have my GetProfiles methods as static, but I thought that adding BindingFlags.Instance should have resolved this?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right that `BindingFlags.Instance` means that your method is not static. As a result, your call to `GetMethod` is not returning `null`.

Instead, the problem is that your `Invoke` call is supplying `null` instead of the object for `this` in the call. It should be the the first parameter. For example, if you want the method to be called for the object on which `Run()` is executing, you should use:

```
typeof(WorkerRole).GetMethod(string.Format("{0}GetProfiles", Firm), 
    BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public).Invoke(this, null);
```

More details on `Invoke` is on [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a89hcwhh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Ok that makes sense - where does my return List<string> end up?  How can I assign that to a variable?

Comment: @Evonet it is returned by the Invoke method as an `object` so you have to cast it to your `List<string>`.